# gas fee on OpenSea

Tags: metamask, gas-price, gas-estimate, fees

First, I'm brand new to the Ethereum platform,  so I do apologise if any of the following is considered stupid questions. Now, I will ask my question anyway

I am setting up the first sale of one of my items on OpenSea (as a trial) using Ethereum

After completing all the settings for the selling method, I clicked on "Add your listing"
I opened my account window in the Meta Mask wallet
OpenSea suggests I pay a gas fee - really it's variable - but it averages around $50
At the same time I opened https://etherscan.io
I found the gas fee 'in the meantime' under $3 on etherscan
Which means that paying the gas fee (twice) required by OpenSea equals $6

Why do I find the gas fee on OpenSea to average $50?

Answer (score 0):

Not every transaction is the same. I'm not super familiar with minting NFTs on opensea but the general idea is that the more complex a transaction is, the more gas it's going to cost. I assume that minting a NFT costs somewhere around 400k gas, and what you saw on etherscan was probably the price for a simple ETH transfer, which only costs 21k gas, hence the price difference